# Error when decrypting a string with Cipher

Tags: android, encryption

I have a password that I encrypt and at reboot decrypt. Here is the code for encryption:

```
static private String EncryptString(String input)
        {
          Log.i(TAG,"EncryptString input = "+input);
          try {
            if(input != null)
            {
              Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(AES_MODE);
              cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, getSecretKey(), new GCMParameterSpec(128, FIXED_IV));
              byte[] encryptData = cipher.doFinal(stringTobyte(input));
              String res = byteToHex(encryptData);
              Log.i(TAG,"String encrypted = "+res);
              return res;
            }
          }
          catch (Exception e) {
              Log.e(TAG,"Exception in EncryptString",e);
              e.printStackTrace();
          }
          return null;
        }

public static String byteToHex(byte[] raw) {
        final String    HEXES    = "0123456789ABCDEF";
        final StringBuilder hex = new StringBuilder(2 * raw.length);
        for (final byte b : raw) {
            hex.append(HEXES.charAt((b & 0xF0) >> 4)).append(HEXES.charAt((b & 0x0F)));
        }
        return hex.toString();
        }
```

and here is the code for decrpytion:

```
static private String DecryptString(String input)
        {
          Log.i(TAG,"DecryptString input = "+input);
          try {
            if(input != null)
            {
              Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(AES_MODE);
              cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, getSecretKey(), new GCMParameterSpec(128, FIXED_IV));
              byte[] decryptData = cipher.doFinal(hexToByte(input));
              return byteToString(decryptData);
            }
          }
          catch (Exception e) {
              Log.e(TAG,"Exception in DecryptString",e);
              e.printStackTrace();
          }
          return null;
        }

public static byte[] hexToByte(String input) {
        int len = input.length();
        if(len % 2 != 0)
        {
        Log.e(TAG,"Cant convert Uneven Hex string to Byte array");
        return null;
        }
        byte[] data = new byte[len / 2];
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i += 2) {
        data[i / 2] = (byte) ((Character.digit(input.charAt(i), 16) << 4)
                         + Character.digit(input.charAt(i+1), 16));
        }
        Log.i(TAG,"hexToByte return data");
        return data;
    }
```

with :

```
private static final byte[] FIXED_IV = new byte[]{ 60, 59, 58, 52, 51, 50,49, 48, 47,46, 45, 44 };

static private Key getSecretKey() {
            try {
                KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(AndroidKeyStore);
                keyStore.load(null);
                if (!keyStore.containsAlias(KEY_ALIAS)) {
                  KeyGenerator keyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance(KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_AES, AndroidKeyStore);
                  keyGenerator.init(new KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(KEY_ALIAS,
                                    KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT | KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT)
                                    .setBlockModes(KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_GCM)
                                    .setEncryptionPaddings(KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_NONE)
                                    .setRandomizedEncryptionRequired(false) 
                                    .build());
                                    keyGenerator.generateKey();
                }
                return keyStore.getKey(KEY_ALIAS, null);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
```

The encryption seems to be ok however when I decrypt, I am getting this error:

> 06-03 11:14:07.938  1638  2039 E WifiXmlUtil: Exception in
> DecryptString 06-03 11:14:07.938  1638  2039 E WifiXmlUtil:
> javax.crypto.AEADBadTagException 06-03 11:14:07.938  1638  2039 E
> WifiXmlUtil:   at
> android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.engineDoFinal(AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.java:517)
> 06-03 11:14:07.938  1638  2039 E WifiXmlUtil:   at
> javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2055) 06-03 11:14:07.938  1638
> 2039 E WifiXmlUtil:   at
> com.android.server.wifi.util.XmlUtil$WifiConfigurationXmlUtil.DecryptString(XmlUtil.java:445)
> 06-03 11:14:07.938  1638  2039 E WifiXmlUtil:   at
> com.android.server.wifi.util.XmlUtil$WifiConfigurationXmlUtil.parseFromXml(XmlUtil.java:672)
> 06-03 11:14:07.938  1638  2039 E WifiXmlUtil:   at
> com.android.server.wifi.NetworkListStoreData.parseNetwork(NetworkListStoreData.java:255)
> 06-03 11:14:07.938  1638  2039 E WifiXmlUtil:   at
> com.android.server.wifi.NetworkListStoreData.parseNetworkList(NetworkListStoreData.java:221)
> 06-03 11:14:07.938  1638  2039 E WifiXmlUtil:   at
> com.android.server.wifi.NetworkListStoreData.deserializeData(NetworkListStoreData.java:91)
> 06-03 11:14:07.938  1638  2039 E WifiXmlUtil:   at
> com.android.server.wifi.WifiConfigStore.deserializeData(WifiConfigStore.java:440)
> 06-03 11:14:07.938  1638  2039 E WifiXmlUtil:   at
> com.android.server.wifi.WifiConfigStore.read(WifiConfigStore.java:362)
> 06-03 11:14:07.938  1638  2039 E WifiXmlUtil:   at
> com.android.server.wifi.WifiConfigManager.loadFromStore(WifiConfigManager.java:2864)
> 06-03 11:14:07.938  1638  2039 E WifiXmlUtil:   at
> com.android.server.wifi.WifiStateMachine$DefaultState.processMessage(WifiStateMachine.java:3524)
> 06-03 11:14:07.938  1638  2039 E WifiXmlUtil:   at
> com.android.internal.util.StateMachine$SmHandler.processMsg(StateMachine.java:992)
> 06-03 11:14:07.938  1638  2039 E WifiXmlUtil:   at
> com.android.internal.util.StateMachine$SmHandler.handleMessage(StateMachine.java:809)
> 06-03 11:14:07.938  1638  2039 E WifiXmlUtil:   at
> android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 06-03
> 11:14:07.938  1638  2039 E WifiXmlUtil:   at
> android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 06-03 11:14:07.938  1638  2039
> E WifiXmlUtil:   at
> android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:65) 06-03 11:14:07.938
> 1638  2039 E WifiXmlUtil: Caused by:
> android.security.KeyStoreException: Signature/MAC verification failed
> 06-03 11:14:07.938  1638  2039 E WifiXmlUtil:   at
> android.security.KeyStore.getKeyStoreException(KeyStore.java:852)
> 06-03 11:14:07.938  1638  2039 E WifiXmlUtil:   at
> android.security.keystore.KeyStoreCryptoOperationChunkedStreamer.doFinal(KeyStoreCryptoOperationChunkedStreamer.java:224)
> 06-03 11:14:07.938  1638  2039 E WifiXmlUtil:   at
> android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreAuthenticatedAESCipherSpi$BufferAllOutputUntilDoFinalStreamer.doFinal(AndroidKeyStoreAuthenticatedAESCipherSpi.java:373)
> 06-03 11:14:07.938  1638  2039 E WifiXmlUtil:   at
> android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.engineDoFinal(AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.java:506)
> 06-03 11:14:07.938  1638  2039 E WifiXmlUtil:   ... 15 more

Moreover, it is working most of the time but when I enroll to testDpc after factory reset, it is not working! Do you have any idea why?

Comment: Just a short warning: in GCM mode using a fixed IV (also called nonce) is the worst you can do if the encryption key is used more than once. Please read https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/26790/how-bad-it-is-using-the-same-iv-twice-with-aes-gcm

Comment: Are you sure your `getSecretKey` method works as expected (generate new key the first time and after that always return the previously generated key). I would add log message when a new key is generated.

Comment: If you encode hexadecimal then you have to decode hexadecimal before decipher.